# How to run number of processes in bunches of thread without using threadPool & used EventWaitHandler for Handling

Tags: c#, multithreading, event-wait-handle

```
  class Process
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int threads = 0;
        int processes = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Total number of processes:");
        processes = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of parallel threads:");
        threads = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        ManualResetEvent[] events = new ManualResetEvent[threads];

        int k = 0, innercount = 0;           
        //----running in bunches
        do
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < threads; l++)
            {
                if (k < threads)
                {
                    events[l] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                    Runner r = new Runner(events[l], innercount);
                    new Thread(new ThreadStart(r.Run)).Start();
                    Console.WriteLine("running start...{0}", innercount);
                    k++;
                    innercount++;
                }
            }
            WaitHandle.WaitAny(events);
            k--;
            Console.WriteLine("Decrement counter...{0}", k);
        }
        while (innercount < processes);

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(events);

        Console.WriteLine("All finished!");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
 class Runner
{
    static readonly object rngLock = new object();
    static Random rng = new Random();

    ManualResetEvent ev;
    int id;

    internal Runner(ManualResetEvent ev, int id)
    {
        this.ev = ev;
        this.id = id;
    }

    internal void Run()
    {

            int sleepTime;
            lock (rngLock)
            {
                sleepTime = rng.Next(2000);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread Runner {0}",
                               id);
            if (ev.Set())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("release thread...{0}", id);
            }
    }
}
```

I have to run multiple threads.If one thread is finishes then start another thread.Problem is that its started all process at the same time.(Seems that this condition not working fine WaitHandle.WaitAny(events);)

1:If 20 threads are running then 21st will be started when One thread releases from 20s thread.

2: Without using threadpool can it be done using EventWaitHandler.

Comment: Can you define the difference between Process and a thread ? (of course in your term)

Comment: I have something 100[process] & want to run in different bunches(10 or 20 [threads]).

Comment: process, you mean logic/functions or processes, like executables?

Comment: (functions) I have to run one function 100 times but on thread & in some bunches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* do something with PLinq and [`WithDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719.aspx).

`WithDegreeOfParallelism` will limit the number of threads that simultaneously run.

The following example shows how to use Plinq to run a number of workers with limited parallelism passing a different object to each worker.

It assumes that you start off with a sequence of objects, and you want to pass each of those objects to a worker method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace Demo
{
    class DataForWorker
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Value;
    };

    class Program
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int numberOfThreadsRunning;

        void Run()
        {
            int maxThreads = 8;

            IEnumerable<DataForWorker> dataForWorkers = getDataForWorkers();

            dataForWorkers
                .AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(maxThreads)
                .ForAll(worker);
        }

        IEnumerable<DataForWorker> getDataForWorkers()
        {
            // Just return some dummy data.

            int numberOfDataItems = 30;

            return Enumerable.Range(1, numberOfDataItems).Select
            (
                n => new DataForWorker
                {
                    ID = n,
                    Value = n.ToString()
                }
            );
        }

        void worker(DataForWorker data)
        {
            int n = Interlocked.Increment(ref numberOfThreadsRunning);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread " + data.ID + " is starting. #threads now = " + n);
            Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(1000, 2000));
            Console.WriteLine("Thread " + data.ID + " is stopping.");
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref numberOfThreadsRunning);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I have to pass object in worker.How can I pass it using above Plink

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) to control the release of your threads. Look at the example there. But I wonder why you cannot use `ThreadPool` to accomplish this?

> The count on a semaphore is decremented each time a thread enters the
>   semaphore, and incremented when a thread releases the semaphore. When
>   the count is zero, subsequent requests block until other threads
>   release the semaphore. When all threads have released the semaphore,
>   the count is at the maximum value specified when the semaphore was
>   created.

This way, once a thread released a slot in your semaphore, another thread can take up that slot and run.